# Scatterplot is freezing my browser in R/Plotly

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, scatter-plot

I am plotting close to 37k points with Plotly/R via shiny and it takes around 40-45 seconds to display and Firefox goes to not responding state while it renders. Is there any solution?

Attaching profvis screenshots:
[image]

[image]

Comment: There are two solutions I think of: 1st create the plot as a pixel graphic and display the image. 2nd use some sort of 2d histogram instead e.g. hexbin.

Comment: Firefox has a general issue with large JS files. Try reducing the size of your data by aggregation or any other suitable method.